# How to create custom tab bar with out selecting any item by default

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls, uitabbar

How to create custom tab bar with out selecting any item by default  we have to show dashboard with 5 tab bar items without selecting any one of them if we click on any one just show particular content with cross option with selected color.

Comment: Please consider to improve your question. It's too vague. Also, you're missing something little, but very important; the dot -> **.** . Did you have done some researches, attempts to solve your problem? Please be aware that StackOverflow is not a " _code for me pl0x_ " site...

Comment: I searched a lot. but i got answers for default selection item only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use buttons instead of the tab bar and you can set the property of button as selected which you want.